# Why does the navcontroller's backstack always have at least 2 items in it?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I create a nav controller like this: `val navController = rememberNavController()`. Then I would like to show a back button only if the user is not at the start destination of the app -- in other words, I need to be able to check if the current entry is the only item in the backstack.

I do this:

```
val backStack by navController.currentBackStack.collectAsState()
if (backStack.size > 1) {
    /* Show back button */
}
```

However, this code always shows the back button, even if I'm on the first page. But when I change it to 2, like `if (backStack.size > 2)` then it works fine.

This seems like an unstable solution to me. Why 2? Is it system specific? Is this guaranteed behavior? I see no documentation on this.

Comment: That method isn't even part of the [public API surface](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController). Since you should have a [fixed start destination](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/principles#fixed_start_destination), you already know exactly what destination is your start destination. Why aren't you using that information?

Comment: @ianhanniballake It is possible to be at your start destination but not at the root of the stack -- for instance, if you navigate to the start destination multiple times.

Comment: That kind of defeats the whole point of a fixed start destination (where that is the signal to the user that you will exit the app if you hit back again). That predictability is a pretty important part behind that Principle of Navigation. Can you explain your concrete case?